# Programmatically switch UItabbarcontroller index & customize

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

From a button inside first viewcontroller of UItabbarcontroller, I want to switch tabbar controller programatically to a second tab index.

`self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];`

I also want to change the text of UILabel, which is within xib of second viewcontroller. How can I do that?

When I access the selectedViewController's IBOutlet there are all null.

Answer (score 2):

Use this method : 
1:

//for navigation

```
[self.tabBarController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES ];


     [self.tabBarController setSelectedViewController:[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1]];
```

2:

```
 - (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

set  label by :

```
for (UIView* subview in [[[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] view] subviews] )
{
    if (    [subview isKindOfClass:[UIlabel class]] )
    {
        // do here
        break;
    }
}
```

This may help you...